# jQuery Unrecognised Expression in Safari Only

Tags: jquery

I have the following code causing an Unrecognised Expression error in Safari only. The error occurs on both OSX and iOS versions of Safari but does not happen in any other browser.

The console says:-

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li[data-page-step="1"
```

The HTMl code to match this selector is:-

```
    <li style=""
      data-page-step="1"
      data-page-label-previous="< Back"
      data-page-label-next="Next"
      data-page-label-number-text="{page} / {total}"
      data-page-disabled="false"
      data-page-hidden="false"
      data-page-fid="f21"

    >
```

And the JS code which is failing this selector expression is as below, which I assume must be correct, because it works everywhere else (other browsers).

```
        v = function(b) {
        var c = {
                step: 1,
                fid: "",
                hidden: !1,
                labelPrevious: "Previous",
                labelNext: "Next",
                progressText: "",
                labelNumberText: "",
                disabled: !1
            },
            d = a('li[data-page-step="' + b + '"');
        if (!d.length) return c;
        for (var e in c) {
            var f = d.data("page" + u(e));
            c[e] = f ? f : ""
        }
        return c.$e = d, c
    }
```

Any ideas why this would fail only on Safari? The [data-next-step...] escaping looks correct - and presumably is correct by other browsers standards.

Comment: Please don't post minified code. Post the code prior to minification.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that code correctly, because - as [T.J. Crowder shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43140050/82548) - you're definitely missing the closing square bracket (`]`) from the attribute-equals selector, which is - or *should be* - a syntax error in every browser.

Comment: Apologies, the code is not my own and the unminified version is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *shouldn't* just be Safari, as this is clearly missing a `]`:

```
d = a('li[data-page-step="' + b + '"]');
// here ----------------------------^
```

...but I can't help but notice that this works just fine on Chrome v56 and Firefox v51, so apparently they're just more tolerant:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-foo="bar"').length);
```

```html
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly this. The closing ] was missing -  very odd that no other browser (including Edge, FF and Chrome) did not complain! Thanks

Comment: @GrantG: Yeah, I **just** updated the above with a snippet that should fail in all browsers, but doesn't in Chrome or Firefox. Apparently they're being tolerant, which I (for one) don't think is a good thing -- as it leaves you open to bugs like this! :-)